# Is there a MYSql function that returns a list of names in a column? the field hold a comma separated list of id's

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select data from a table that contains a column with comma separated id's, and return the values in a comma separated column.

table events has a column instructors with data like "1,2,3,4"
I want to return each row with the instructors column looking like:
"Dave, Harry, John, Mike"

Thanks for any help you can give!

I have tried using group_concat() but have not been able to return the proper data. sometimes it returns null.

```
SELECT et.title AS 'Event Type', e.instructor, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i.instructor_name SEPARATOR ' - ') FROM instructor i WHERE i.instructor_id = e.event_id) AS idlist
FROM EVENTS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN event_type et ON (et.id = e.event_type)
ORDER BY e.event_id
```

This is my results

```
Event Type    instructor    idlist
Training      10             Rich
Training      5              Steve
Training      5              James
Training      10,40          \N
Training      19             Mike
Training      10,25,39,40    Tim
Training      10,40,39,25    William
Training      26             \N
```

I expect 10,40 to be Rich, John but it is returning null.
Also, 5 is returning different names.

ed.

```
Some table data:

instructor_id   instructor_name
1   Ritchie
2   Zane
3   Mark
5   Mike
6   Tim
7   David
8   Jeff
9   Chase
10  Gene
26  Steve
27  James
40  John

event_id    event_type  instructor
1   2   10
2   2   39
3   2   22
4   2   10,40
5   2   19
6   2   26
7   2   39
8   2   25
9   2   39
10  2   22
11  2   22
12  2   39
13  2   10,25,39,40
14  2   10,40,39,25
15  2   10
16  2   26
```

Comment: *"comma separated id's*" There's your problem. Your schema is bad and it's going to cause a LOT of heart burn. Essentially you need to break that comma delimited list out so that each item in the list has it's own record, then with that you can join properly to your `instructor` table and do all the group concat's you want for your output.

Comment: Post sample data of both tables.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am unable to change the structure of the table at this point. The 3rd party (Scheduler) code that I am using has defined the column this way.  I am trying to do some reporting/ exporting the data to excel for the users.

Comment: I know that what I'm going to say will no solve it, but maybe it's going to be easier if you use a backend language, such as PHP. Just turn that **ids** into **array**, loop through the array and for each id, run a query.

Comment: @Brhaka  thanks for the input,  I was going to do thaat but thought there was a way to do it in the sql statement.  the table contains other id fields but they are 1 to 1.  Maybe I can try and do it for this one column. Just wondering on process time.  Will let you know.

Comment: Ok, I'm waiting! : )

Comment: This is my first time posting on this site and I want to say there where some quick responses. I want to thank each one of you that took the time to try and help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the use of the operator `LIKE` to join the tables `events` and `instructor`:

```
select
  et.title `Event Type`,
  e.instructor,
  group_concat(i.instructor_name order by i.instructor_id SEPARATOR ' - ' ) idlist
from events e 
inner join event_type et on et.id = e.eventtype
inner join instructor i on concat(',', e.instructor, ',')  like concat('%,', i.instructor_id, ',%')
group by 
  e.event_id,
  et.title,
  e.instructor
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9UgSfYMjjVU2XdYAQ6mrZG/1).
Results:

```
| Event Type | instructor  | idlist                      |
| ---------- | ----------- | --------------------------- |
| Training   | 10          | Gene                        |
| Training   | 39          | Bbbbb                       |
| Training   | 10,40       | Gene - John                 |
| Training   | 26          | Steve                       |
| Training   | 39          | Bbbbb                       |
| Training   | 25          | Aaaaa                       |
| Training   | 39          | Bbbbb                       |
| Training   | 39          | Bbbbb                       |
| Training   | 10,25,39,40 | Gene - Aaaaa - Bbbbb - John |
| Training   | 10,40,39,25 | Gene - Aaaaa - Bbbbb - John |
| Training   | 10          | Gene                        |
| Training   | 26          | Steve                       |
```

I added 2 `instructor_name`s for the ids 25 and 39 because they were not included in your sample data.

Comment: Thanks for your solution!  This is exactly what I was looking for.